# Multidimensional Array to table cells

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array and I am trying to output the information into a table that is 4 cells wide. The formatting of the table works great, but I am not able to echo the array information. Anybody knows how it can be done?

Array looks like this:

```
[1] => Array 
    ( 
        [photo_id] => 76 
        [photo_name] => 1284d830b198f21ee851334ab87140e1 
    ) 

[2] => Array 
    ( 
        [photo_id] => 75 
        [photo_name] => 6ef145dd3f52e807f3d7afb3810a2ef8 
    ) 

[3] => Array 
    ( 
        [photo_id] => 74 
        [photo_name] => f116f3a778d5e900a9e4f7b60c530b67 
    ) 

[4] => Array 
    ( 
        [photo_id] => 73 
        [photo_name] => 87b2091970c85254391f1245f1826604 
    ) 

[5] => Array 
    ( 
        [photo_id] => 72 
        [photo_name] => 549c75f04964d219974d4ceffa039e89 
    ) 

)
```

PHP Code:

```
  echo "<table border=\"1\">\n"; 
for ($counter=0;  $counter<$results;  ) { 
    echo "<tr>\n"; 
    for ($colcount=0;  $colcount<4 AND $counter<$results;  $colcount++,$counter++) {
        echo "<td>1</td>"; 
    } 
    if ($counter == $results) { 
        for ($extra = ($results % 4);  $extra<4 AND $extra!=0;  $extra++) { 

        echo "<td>0</td>"; 

        } 
    } 
    echo "\n</tr>\n"; 
} 
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Where/what is your array, in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only see three cells but here is how you could do it.

```
<?php
$test = array(1 => array('photo_id' => '76', 'photo_name' => '1284d830b198f21ee851334ab87140e1'), 
            '2' => array('photo_id' => '75', 'photo_name' => '6ef145dd3f52e807f3d7afb3810a2ef8'), 
            '3' => array('photo_id' => '74', 'photo_name' => 'f116f3a778d5e900a9e4f7b60c530b67'),
            4 => array('photo_id' => '73', 'photo_name' => '1284d830b198f21ee851334ab87140e1'), 
            '5' => array('photo_id' => '72', 'photo_name' => '6ef145dd3f52e807f3d7afb3810a2ef8'), 
            '6' => array('photo_id' => '71', 'photo_name' => 'f116f3a778d5e900a9e4f7b60c530b67'),
            7 => array('photo_id' => '70', 'photo_name' => '1284d830b198f21ee851334ab87140e1'), 
            '8' => array('photo_id' => '69', 'photo_name' => '6ef145dd3f52e807f3d7afb3810a2ef8'), 
            '9' => array('photo_id' => '68', 'photo_name' => 'f116f3a778d5e900a9e4f7b60c530b67')
            );
echo '<table border="1">' . "\n";
echo '<tr><td>ID</td><td>PhotoId</td><td>Location/name</td></tr>'  . "\n";
$count = 0;
foreach($test as $id => $photoinfo) {
    foreach($photoinfo as $key => $value) {
        if ($count % 4 == 0  && !empty($pid)) {
            echo '<tr>';
        }
        if($key == 'photo_id') {
            $pid = $value;
        }
        if ($key == 'photo_name') {
            $name = $value;
        }
        if(!empty($pid) && !empty($name)) {
            echo "<td>" . $pid . " " . $name . "</td>\n";
            $count++;
            if ($count % 4 == 0) {
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            unset($name, $pid);
        }
    }
}
if ($count % 4 != 0) {
    //we finished the table generation with less than 4 cells
    while($count % 4 != 0) {
        echo '<td>empty cell</td>';
        $count++;
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

Output:

```
 <table border="1">
<tr><td>ID</td><td>PhotoId</td><td>Location/name</td></tr>
<tr><td>76 1284d830b198f21ee851334ab87140e1</td>
<td>75 6ef145dd3f52e807f3d7afb3810a2ef8</td>
<td>74 f116f3a778d5e900a9e4f7b60c530b67</td>
<td>73 1284d830b198f21ee851334ab87140e1</td>
</tr><tr><td>72 6ef145dd3f52e807f3d7afb3810a2ef8</td>
<td>71 f116f3a778d5e900a9e4f7b60c530b67</td>
<td>70 1284d830b198f21ee851334ab87140e1</td>
<td>69 6ef145dd3f52e807f3d7afb3810a2ef8</td>
</tr><tr><td>68 f116f3a778d5e900a9e4f7b60c530b67</td>
<td>empty cell</td><td>empty cell</td><td>empty cell</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: i would need to put this array information into each cell for example this would be in the first cell                                               [1] => Array 
    ( 
        [photo_id] => 76 
        [photo_name] => 1284d830b198f21ee851334ab87140e1 
    )

Comment: You want each part of that in a cell, no?

Comment: for example i need the photo_id and the photo name in 1 cell, than the next cell would be the next part of the array

Comment: So you want `<td>76 1284d830b198f21ee851334ab87140e1</td>` in cell 1? If correct what goes in the next cell?

Comment: 75 and 6ef145dd3f52e807f3d7afb3810a2ef8

Comment: for example the table would look like this <table>
<tr>
<td>76 1284d830b198f21ee851334ab87140e1</td>
<td>75 6ef145dd3f52e807f3d7afb3810a2ef8</td>
<td>74 f116f3a778d5e900a9e4f7b60c530b67</td> 
<td>73 87b2091970c85254391f1245f1826604</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>72 549c75f04964d219974d4ceffa039e89</td> 
<td> (empty cell) </td>
<td> (empty cell) </td>
<td> (empty cell) </td>
</tr>
</table>

Comment: Okay, updated. I thought the table was for data, not displaying purposes. For future reference it's better to use CSS for displaying/styling data.

Comment: ok yes that is getting close, but it does not insert empty td cells

Comment: Just added that bit in as well.

Comment: thank you! i have been staring at that for hours today!